# Get text from UITextField from the custom cells class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a custom `UITableViewCell`. In it, I have `buttons` and `textFields`. When a button is selected (a button in `mainVC.m`), I want to get the text the user inserted. Is there a way I can access it in `mainVC.m` and not in `customCell.m` file?